# Fragment width MATCH_PARENT not filling screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

This is the layout that hosts the fragment. When the fragment is displayed I can tell it's width is wrapping content even though it should be the width of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.mferreira.crm.recordSwipeActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_item_view" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is the fragment itself. You can see that it's set to MATCH_PARENT for Width so I'm unsure as to why it's wrapping the content instead.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mferreira.crm.itemFragment1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Not sure, but it might have something to do with padding in your fragment's RelativeLayout.

Comment: @slanecek just tried it, still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I still don't have enough reps to comment because this is a new account. But how do you use your frame layout? Maybe you've put it between something that has margins that move it.

Comment: Yeah so it goes underneath another layout inside a viewpager

Comment: What does android:fitsSystemWindows do exactly?
I also think it's the padding. But you didn't do nothing inside the class regarding the layout, did you? There are times before that Android Studio was buggy, what I did was copy the whole layout, made a new file and pasted, and it worked. Maybe try that?